# How to have two submit actions for a form in Laravel?

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-blade

In case the title is not so clear:

I have a form and two submit buttons( or I can use one submit button and the other one could be just a button or an anchor tag) and want each one to submit my form to a different action...

any help is so much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the second submit button a HTML name, then check to see if that name is set in the POST statement.

```
<input name="back" type="submit" value="Go Back">
<input name="next" type="submit" value="Continue">
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, but you see the client want this the other way that I've explained in the answer, two different actions, what do to with that?

I should thank you for the time you've put dear

Comment: Are you against using Javascript to submit the form and have it listening for the anchor tag being clicked?

Comment: I'd like to accomplish it without using javascript but If there's not gonna be any other way, then that would be my last choice of course

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to use jQuery to accomplish that. When you construct your form, leave out the method altogether. Then, give your two buttons and `id`:

```
<button id="submit-1">Submit 1</button>
<button id="submit-2">Submit 2</button>
```

Then, use `jQuery.post` or `jQuery.ajax` to submit your form data.

See these articles for more info:

1. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
2. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'd like to accomplish it without using javascript but If there's not gonna be any other way, then that would be my last choice of course

thanks for the time

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to ["flash"](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input) the data.

In your routes:

```
Route::post('/test', 'TestController@postTest');
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@getTest');
Route::any('/testSubmit1Action', function()
{
    var_dump(Input::old());
});
```

And then your TestController:

```
class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function postTest()
    {
        // Refer to getTest() below for how these buttons are named.
        // We can check for the existence of a certain button and process
        if(Input::has('submit1'))
        {
            // Redirect to different route / URI
            Input::flash();
            return Redirect::to('/testSubmit1Action');

            // Alternatively, you could process action 1 here
        }

        if(Input::has('submit2'))
        {
            // Process action 2
        }
    }

    public function getTest()
    {
        // I recommend putting this in a view / blade template
        // eg... return View::make('foo.bar');
        echo Form::open();
        echo Form::submit('Submit Action 1', array('name' => 'submit1'));
        echo Form::submit('Submit Action 2', array('name' => 'submit2'));
        echo Form::close();
    }

}
```